# Браузер или броузер?

Tags: иностранные-слова

В английском  в слове "browser" О читается как среднее между А и О. По-русски говорят и так и этак. А есть ли какая-то норма написания?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вообще словари (разные) дают разные варианты - или **браузер**, или **броузер**, но в текущий момент времени правильным написанием считается **браузер**.

Comment: А какие словари придерживаются иной точки зрения? 
Даже если это только один-единственный, но профильный (а здесь почти все можно считать таковыми) и современный, то утверждение "правильным написанием считается" - под большим вопросом.  

ЗЫ Я лично брОузера уже лет десять не слыхивал.

Comment: "Броузер" дает "Словарь иностранных слов" за авторством Комлева Н.Г., 2006.
Всего лишь 6 лет тому назад.

Comment: В правописании ориентируемся на орфографические словари. Желательно академические.

Answer (score 10):

Орфографические словари фиксируют написание с А - браузер.